# Real matrix decompose into symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Using Jordan standard form, we can prove

**Any complex matrix can be decomposed into the product of two symmetric matrices, and one of them is invertible.**

then how to prove that

**Any real square matrix can be decomposed into the product of two symmetric matrices, and at least one of them is invertible.**
?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000326/are-jordan-formable-matrices-closed-under-multiplication/3000980#3000980

Comment: If I remember correctly (but I'm not 100% sure), Irving Kaplansky's *Linear Algebra and Geometry: A Second Course* (Dover) also has a proof.

Comment: @Widawensen thanks.

Comment: @user1551 thanks.